# iText7 Tabbing for paragraphs

Tags: itext7

My requirement is build pdf as below using iText 7.

[image]

Using the below code.

```
Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(2)).useAllAvailableWidth();
        table.addCell(getNameCell("First Lastname", TextAlignment.LEFT));
        // table.addCell(getCell("Text in the middle", TextAlignment.CENTER));
        table.addCell(getLogoCell("Company", TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        table.addCell(getAddressCell("1111 Boones Ridge Rd", TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table.addCell(getLogoCell(" ", TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        table.addCell(getAddressCell("Acworth, Ga 30102", TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table.addCell(getLogoCell(" ", TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        table.addCell(getAddressCell("P: 1234567890", TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table.addCell(getLogoCell(" ", TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        table.addCell(getAddressCell("test@gmail.com", TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table.addCell(getLogoCell(" ", TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        table.addCell(getAddressCell("www.testonline.com", TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table.addCell(getLogoCell(" ", TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        doc.add(table);
```

Here, unnecessarily adding empty space or else text gets aligned horizontally. Also, since the right text font is bigger, there is a space b/w the name and address. Is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

iText 7 has tab stops functionality. You can add a tab and align the text to the right in the following way:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.addTabStops(new TabStop(PageSize.A4.getRight() - document.getLeftMargin() - document.getRightMargin(),
        TabAlignment.RIGHT));
p.add(new Text("Hello")).add(new Tab()).add(new Text("World"));
```

To tweak spacing between your name and address, you may play around with leading property:

```
p.setFixedLeading(12);
```

Comment: Adding multiple text like, p.add(new Text("Hello")).add(new Tab()).add(new Text("World"));  p.add(new Text("Test")); Hello and Test gets aligned in the same line not in the next line.